# Tax nexus for remote working

Tags: united-states, taxes, florida, arizona

I currently work for a company based in Florida. We sell merchandise and entry to sporting events in many states including Arizona.

If I work remotely from Arizona, will it trigger a tax nexus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I currently work for a company based in Florida. We sell merchandise
> and entry to sporting events in many states including Arizona.
>
> If I work remotely from Arizona, will it trigger a tax nexus?

If you sit in Arizona while working, it doesn't matter where the company is located, or where the customers are located, you have Arizona income.  Now if you travel to other states while working then that is a different story.

Where the company is located, where the customers are located, and where the employees are located can make a difference to the taxes of the company.